# Azure Devops Template. How to launch error on condition

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to do `Azure Pipeline yml` template to set versions of `C#` projects.
Depending on type of project (Xamarin, NetFramework, or NetCore) I have to use different task.

I see that it's possible to set conditions on tasks. But I want to set pipeline process as failed if none of the tasks are executed.

For example if someone calls this template with type parameter as *blabla* none of the tasks will be executed. How can I set the pipeline as failed?

```
parameters:
- name: displayName
  type: string

- name: type
  type: string

- name: sourcePath
  type: string
  
- name: fileName
  type: string
  
- name: versionNumber 
  type: string 

steps:
- task: Assembly-Info-NetFramework@3
  displayName: ${{ parameters.displayName }}
  condition: ${{ eq(parameters.type, 'NetFw') }}
  inputs:
    Path: ${{ parameters.sourcePath }}
    FileNames: ${{ parameters.fileName }}
    InsertAttributes: false
    FileEncoding: 'auto'
    WriteBOM: false
    VersionNumber: ${{ parameters.versionNumber }}
    FileVersionNumber: ${{ parameters.versionNumber }}
    LogLevel: 'verbose'
    FailOnWarning: false
    DisableTelemetry: false

- task: Assembly-Info-NetCore@3
  displayName: ${{ parameters.displayName }}
  condition: ${{ eq(parameters.type, 'NetCore') }}
  inputs:
    Path: ${{ parameters.sourcePath }}
    FileNames: ${{ parameters.fileName }}
    InsertAttributes: false
    FileEncoding: 'auto'
    WriteBOM: false
    VersionNumber: ${{ parameters.versionNumber }}
    FileVersionNumber: ${{ parameters.versionNumber }}
    LogLevel: 'verbose'
    FailOnWarning: false
    DisableTelemetry: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) as an alternative for conditions. In this case, you'll get only the needed resulting steps based on your parameters. Example for `exit -1`:

```
- ${{if and(ne(parameters.env_param, 'DEV'),ne(parameters.env_param, 'TEST'))}}:
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: 'exit -1'
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work,. With conditional insertion it's better than condition on tasks and also I see that I can specify values in template and if put wron value the pipeline doesn't works, it is not necessary the check tasks to exit with error

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to set pipeline process as failed if none of the tasks are
> executed.

In this case, your `parameters.type` will not have values `NetFw` and `NetCore`. You may add a new simple step:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  condition: ${{ and(ne(parameters.type, 'NetCore'),ne(parameters.type, 'NetFw')) }}
  inputs:
    script: 'exit -1'
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I'll try with that. I have seen a visual inconveninece with my template. If you see the template onle one task will be executed, but in the execution plan it appears both tasks all the times that I use the template. Is there any way to hide tasks from execution plan?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "the template onle one task will be executed, but in the execution plan it appears both tasks"? There are two different tasks "Assembly-Info-NetFramework@3" and "Assembly-Info-NetCore@3" in your yaml file.

Comment: In the yml template, depending on type parameter "NetCore" or "NetFw" only one task will be executed, but in the azure execution plan interface appears both tasks, one executed (green tick icon) and the other one in grey color as not executed. It's possible to hide the not executed task from the execution plan?

Comment: @JuanDYB check my second answer.